# Trip.js: onFinishStep and onStartStep

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to make my webapp more usable, I wanted to use some king of step-by-step user guide within the application, so the user knows what, when and where to click to achieve its aims.

So, after a lot of researching, I came up with [trip.js](http://eragonj.github.io/Trip.js/), which is stylable and pretty much customizable.

BUT! When trying to do some of my steps, I missed two functions: `onFinishStep` and `onStartStep`.

Yes, you have an event, called `onTripChange` and, here, taking into account the `index` of the step, you can do some actions. But, what if I want to make an action just after a step ends? It wouldn't be executed until next step starts, and that would be too late.

I don't know if there is any hidden functionality (or not so hidden) that I may missed, but I've read the [Docs](http://eragonj.github.io/Trip.js/doc/Trip.html) and there seems not to be any. Also, looking through the code I cannot find any calls executed this way.

So, what I'm asking for is how to make it to achieve this: two functions, one executed right when the step starts and one executed just when it has ended.

Answer (score 1):

After a little of reading the code, I came up with a little piece of text that would do the result.

As of version 2.0.2, into `trip.js` file, after line 386 (inside `next()` function), write the following to execute the function `onFinishStep()`:

```
if(this.tripData[this.tripIndex].onFinishStep !== undefined) this.tripData[this.tripIndex].onFinishStep()
```

As of `onStartStep()`, it would be after line 585 (inside `run()` function):

```
if(this.tripData[this.tripIndex].onStartStep !== undefined) this.tripData[this.tripIndex].onStartStep()
```

That would do the trick. It's working on my tests (Chrome 40, Firefox 35.0.1).

The definition, then, of the steps, would be:

```
var trip = new Trip([
      { sel : $("#element"), content : '<p>The content</p>', position : "n", onFinishStep: function(){/*your code here*/}},
      { sel : $("#element_2"), content : '<p>The content of step 2</p>',  position : "n", onStartStep: function(){/*your code here*/}}
    ], tripjs_general_options)

trip.start()
```

Hope it helps someone.

*I'd like to thank [EragonJ](https://github.com/EragonJ) - the author of [Trip.js](http://eragonj.github.io/Trip.js/) - for such an amazing plugin.*

Kind regards.